# What are possible tweaks when a protein expression from a plasmid shipped on paper fails?

Tags: proteins, plasmids, protein-expression, ecoli

In my group we recently tried to express a protein necessary to perform an analytical method in BL21(DE3). The first two attempts did fail and no colonies did grow on the agarose. I hear, that the extraction of plasmid from paper and resoubilization is more prone to error in comparison to plasmid that is shipped in liquid form and this is a known issue. I am wondering what could be possible workarounds to try to still get it working. Until know, I have the following ideas:

- Increase plasmid concentration
- Decrease antibiotic concentration
- Use a different strain like NEB 5 alpha

I am also wondering if the X-Ray treatment of customes service could facilitate in any way plasmid determination or is this an urban myth?

Comment: How did you prepare the plasmid from the paper? Did you do a transformation and a mini prep first?

Comment: No miniprep. I took the sheet of paper and cut it leaving a small portion as backup. Solubilzed the plasmid with 50 microliter TE buffer, resulting in a plasmid concentration of 11 ng/ml. Using 4 microliter plasmid with 25 microliter bacteria culture. Did not work. Than increased to 10 microliter plasmid, did not work. I observed now increased plasmid concentration of ca. 17 ng/ml after adding 100 DNSase free water destilled water and letting it stand over night.

Comment: Ok: My advice in these cases would be to first transform some standard competent cells (DH5a or likewise), cultivate them, make a prep and check your plasmid at least on a gel, ideally but restriction digest. Also make some glycerol stocks. So you make sure you have the right plasmid and you have a stock you can always go back to.

Comment: I will consider this after my current experiment batch. I will do 5 plates, 2 with Ecoli 21D3 and two with NEB5 alpha, two different antibiotic concentration and 1 plate just with LB media at the smaller antibiotic concentration. Therefore I should be able to reduce the amount of possible error sources based on the outcome of the experiment. When not a single of 4 plates show colonies I agree, the integrity of the plasmid is in doubt.

Comment: I think that your title here is entirely misleading - you aren't looking at protein expression in this case, simply transformation of the bacteria with a plasmid. Frist step is to test that your system works with your cells and plasmid and with known good cells and plasmid - beg/borrow known good competent cells and plasmid from a colleague and test them in parallel with your cells and plasmid. Note that you need [competent cells](https://blog.addgene.org/save-time-and-money-by-making-your-own-competent-cells) for this, not just bacterial culture.

Comment: You're right. Goal is of course the expression after the trafo. Cells are competent. In the meantime I also got colonies and we will do a miniprep and check the plasmid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it helped to treat the filterpaper longer with miliq water to increase plasmid concentration. I also used more plasmid in the 3rd attempt and it worked. Miniprep was performed nevertheless. When a similar experiment is not working, I would recommend to increase plasmid concentration, increase incubation time and decrease antibiotics in that order. I tested the plasmid on agarose gel and further I sent the plasmid further to a sequencing service for validation. Seems all to checkout.